# I wish to index all drives except 'C' which is SSD

Tags: windows-7, ssd

I have a 240 GB SSD as my 'c' drive & it has all of my programs on it. Everything else documents, videos, music etc are on other drives.  Windows 7 64 bit doesn't seem to allow me to do this.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Your question makes little sense, could you reword it or add more detail?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the locations on which Windows makes the indexes.

To to the `Control Panel` and open `Indexing Options`. Then hit `Modify` to choose the indexed folders or disks.

Screenshot of the settings:
[image]